# Auto-complete for random multiple ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have random fields for entries. I need to autocomplete using java script and php, but when I try it auto commplete only first field.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $(".name").keyup(function() {     
        $(".name").autocomplete("get_profile_list.php", {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            selectFirst: true
        });
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function track() {
     var count = jQuery('.abc').length;
     jQuery('#track1').append('<span id="track1" class="abc"><br><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name-'+count+'" class="name" value="" size="35"/><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty-'+count+'" value="" size="1"  onchange="return track();" /><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price-'+count+'" value="" size="1"/></span>'); 
}

$('input').live("keypress", function(e) {
    /* ENTER PRESSED*/
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /* FOCUS ELEMENT */
        var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(":input");
        var idx = inputs.index(this);

        if (idx == inputs.length - 1) {
            inputs[0].select()
        } else {
            inputs[idx + 1].focus(); //  handles submit buttons
            inputs[idx + 1].select();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");?>

    <form name="form" method="post">
        Party Name : <input type="text" name="customer" size="30" />
        Date and Time : <input type="hidden" name="edt" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y h:i:s", time());?>"/><?php echo date("d-m-Y h:i:s", time());?>
        <br><br>
        <strong>Products Details</strong>
        <div id="main">
            <span id="track1" class="abc">
            <input type="text" name="name[]" id="name-0" class="name" value="" size="35" /><input type="text" name="qty[]" id="qty-0" value="" size="1"  onchange="return track();" /><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price-0" value="" size="1"/>
            </span>
            <div id="display">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        Receiver Name<input type="text" name="receiver" /><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For example please visit http://computerdada.com/slip1.php

In product details first input box is name of product please test it using words
key, lan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

you are adding element with class `name` dynamically so the elements that are not presernt at DOM ready doesn't get event handler attached to it.

you need [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach the event handler to the parent element present at DOM ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#track1').on('keyup', '.name', function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("get_profile_list.php", {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            selectFirst: true
        });
    });
});
```

---

**Updated after OP's comment.**

As you are using `jQuery v1.3.2`

so you have to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.name').live('keyup', function () {
        $(this).autocomplete("get_profile_list.php", {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            selectFirst: true
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry dear its not working. visit http://computerdada.com/slip1.php here new code

Comment: its working but a new issue is there is also refresh recorde when i try to select from list check

Comment: @SagarSaroha What issue i can't get you ??

Comment: please visit http://computerdada.com/slip1.php and type lan then try to select 4 lan option using down arrow keys. it refresh list when key is free (keyup)

Comment: @SagarSaroha Try `change` instead of `keyup` .

Comment: @SagarSaroha try changing the src attribute of autocomplete script to `<script type='text/javascript' src='auto/jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>` .Makes use of `/` not `\\` .